# If a method takes a ragged array, the parameters for that method would be int[][] or int[]?

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array, methods, jagged-arrays

I just took a test and the professor asked us to write a method that takes a ragged array as a parameter. He provided the header and it was:

```java
public static int myMethod(int[] myArray)
```

I am 99% positive that the parameters have to be `int[][] myArray` because it is a ragged (2d) array.

Did my professor make a mistake or did I get a question wrong?

Answer (score 2):

A ragged (or jagged) array is an array of arrays of different sizes. If you're talking about `int`s, the argument type would definitely be `int [][]`.

It's hard to tell who got what wrong here, but either you or your professor definitely missed something - `public static int myMethod(int [] myArray)` by no means takes a ragged array.

Answer (score 0):

Since *Java 5* you can use [*varargs*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/relnotes/features.html#varargs) in the method signature. Maybe your professor meant something like this. This method prints a kind of jagged 2d array:

```java
public static int myMethod(int[]... myArray) {
    System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(myArray));
    return 0;
}
```

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    myMethod(new int[2], new int[]{1, 2, 3}, null);
}
```

Output:

```
[[0, 0], [1, 2, 3], null]
```